# Maven Project Executable Jar Built in Eclipse IDE Not Finding Resource

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, unicenta

Having a livid time trying to figure out a compile problem.

I am branching off of an existing Maven project and mid-project I switched from the Netbeans IDE to Eclipse IDE (yesterday, actually). The project runs *perfectly* when I run it from inside of the Eclipse IDE. However, when I compile the project to a self-contained executable jar it can no longer find the getClass().getResource() pathing.

I am assuming there is a compiler issue or something when translating this to the jar?

Project path is: /src/main/resources/Images
IDE Target is: target/classes/Images
In the JAR it is in: resources/Images

Is this correct, or am I missing something painfully obvious?

The console error message is:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
> at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)

The code that is throwing this event is:

```
jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/com/openbravo/images/unicenta.png"));
```

In order to troubleshoot and test for `NULL` I slide this in before the line:

```
System.out.println("Testing Resource: " + getClass().getResource("/com/openbravo/images/unicenta.png"));
```

When executing from the **IDE** I get this (properly) returned:

> Testing Resource: file:/C:/Users/Fearfullsmile/Documents/My%20Programs/KB_Mercantile/target/classes/com/openbravo/images/unicenta.png

When executing from the **Executable JAR** I get `NULL`:

> Testing Resource: null

If someone could please offer me some direction I would be greatly appreciative. Not trying to re-work the wheel, but this seems like it should work! I will be working on this all night, so if I come up with the solution I will update as soon as possible.  :)

Thanks!

**UPDATES:**

As per request, here are the contents of `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.unicenta</groupId>
  <artifactId>unicentaopos</artifactId>
  <version>4.6.4</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <kotlin.version>1.3.70</kotlin.version>
    <!-- Specify this via command line i.e -Dbitrock.exec=/path/to/bitrock/builder-->
    <bitrock.exec/>
    <!-- windows, osx, linux -->
    <bitrock.platform/>
    <!-- Licence location -->
    <bitrock.licence/>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
      <artifactId>core</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
      <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
      <version>11</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
      <version>11</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
    <version>11</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
    <version>11</version>
  </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.6</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcommon</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.24</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
      <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt</groupId>
      <artifactId>core</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.0-v_771</version>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
      <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
      <version>3.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.barcode4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>barcode4j</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
      <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
      <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>oro</groupId>
      <artifactId>oro</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.beanshell</groupId>
      <artifactId>bsh</artifactId>
      <version>2.0b4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bidib.jbidib.org.qbang.rxtx</groupId>
      <artifactId>rxtxcomm</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jpos</groupId>
      <artifactId>jpos</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.10</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.sleepycat</groupId>
          <artifactId>je</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.swinglabs.swingx</groupId>
      <artifactId>swingx-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.5-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>axis</groupId>
      <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
      <artifactId>axis-jaxrpc</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
      <artifactId>saaj-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>axis</groupId>
      <artifactId>axis-wsdl4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
      <version>0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.swinglabs</groupId>
      <artifactId>swing-layout</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sourceforge.javacsv</groupId>
      <artifactId>javacsv</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.netbeans.external</groupId>
      <artifactId>AbsoluteLayout</artifactId>
      <version>RELEASE82</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.javapos</groupId>
      <artifactId>jpos</artifactId>
      <version>1.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.49</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
      <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
      <version>10.10.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.b2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.posapps</groupId>
      <artifactId>posapps-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.9</version>
      <classifier>exe</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Batik Dependencies now wrapped included in apache xmlgraphics fop   -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlgraphics/fop -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
      <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
      <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
      <version>6.4.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
          <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
      <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
      <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
      <version>4.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Commercial version -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
      <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.sciss/weblaf -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>de.sciss</groupId>
      <artifactId>weblaf</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.9</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </exclusion>

      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.dalsemi.onewire</groupId>
      <artifactId>OneWireAPI</artifactId>
      <version>0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- 4.2.2 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.usb4java</groupId>
      <artifactId>usb4java</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.usb</groupId>
      <artifactId>usb-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jdatepicker</groupId>
      <artifactId>jdatepicker</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sleepycat/je -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sleepycat</groupId>
      <artifactId>je</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.73</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Kotlin -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
      <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
      <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.pushingpixels</groupId>
      <artifactId>trident</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.pushingpixels</groupId>
      <artifactId>substance</artifactId>
      <version>7.1.00</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>9.4.1208</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>de.sciss</groupId>
      <artifactId>weblaf-ui</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.3</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <!-- Kotlin -->
      <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
              <archive>
                  <manifest>
                      <mainClass>com.openbravo.pos.forms.StartPOS</mainClass>
                  </manifest>
              </archive>
              <descriptorRefs>
                  <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
              </descriptorRefs>
          </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>compile</id>
            <phase>process-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>test-compile</id>
            <phase>process-test-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
              <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
              <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
              <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
              <mainClass>com.openbravo.pos.forms.StartPOS</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
              <resources>
                <resource>
                  <targetPath>${basedir}/target/lib/Windows</targetPath>
                  <directory>${basedir}/src/other/Windows</directory>
                  <filtering>false</filtering>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                  <targetPath>${basedir}/target/lib/Linux</targetPath>
                  <directory>${basedir}/src/other/Linux</directory>
                  <filtering>false</filtering>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                  <targetPath>${basedir}/target/lib/Mac_OS_X</targetPath>
                  <directory>${basedir}/src/other/Mac_OS_X</directory>
                  <filtering>false</filtering>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                  <targetPath>${basedir}/target/</targetPath>
                  <directory>${basedir}/src/scripts</directory>
                  <filtering>false</filtering>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                  <targetPath>${basedir}/target/licensing</targetPath>
                  <directory>${basedir}/src/installer/licensing</directory>
                  <filtering>false</filtering>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                  <targetPath>${basedir}/target/Bonus</targetPath>
                  <directory>${basedir}/src/other/Bonus</directory>
                  <filtering>false</filtering>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                  <targetPath>${basedir}/target/Configs</targetPath>
                  <directory>${basedir}/src/other/Configs</directory>
                  <filtering>false</filtering>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                  <targetPath>${basedir}/target/Templates</targetPath>
                  <directory>${basedir}/src/other/Templates</directory>
                  <filtering>false</filtering>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                  <targetPath>${basedir}/target/reports/com</targetPath>
                  <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/com</directory>
                  <filtering>false</filtering>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                  <targetPath>${basedir}/target/locales</targetPath>
                  <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                  <filtering>false</filtering>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>com/**</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                </resource>
              </resources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <!-- BitRock -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <executable>${bitrock.exec}</executable>
          <arguments>
            <argument>build</argument>
            <argument>${basedir}/src/installer/unicentaopos.xml</argument>
            <argument>${bitrock.platform}</argument>
            <argument>--license</argument>
            <argument>${bitrock.licence}</argument>
          </arguments>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
          <debug>true</debug>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <extensions>
      <extension>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
        <artifactId>wagon-ftp</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
      </extension>
    </extensions>
    <finalName>unicentaopos</finalName>
  </build>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>unicenta-repo</id>
      <url>http://repo.unicenta.org/maven2/</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <!--These are needed for Swing/Netbeans -->
    <repository>
      <id>netbeans</id>
      <name>NetBeans</name>
      <url>http://netbeans.apidesign.org/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>unicenta-repo</id>
      <url>ftp://repo.unicenta.org/</url>
      <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
  <name>unicentaopos</name>
</project>
```

**JDK Version** is: *jdk1.8.0_202*

**Maven Version** is: *Apache Maven 3.9.4*

**Eclipse IDE Version** is: *2023-09 (4.29.0)*

**Plugin Installed:** *Lombok v1.18.30 "Envious Ferret"*

Comment: Please show your pom file, which JDK version, Maven version etc. you are using?

Comment: Updated with the information as per your reqest!

Comment: You mentioned `Images` with an upper-case `I` but also `images` with lower-case `i`. Is this a typo or the cause (it would work only on a case insensitive file system, but not in a JAR).

Comment: Loading an resource from your `src/main/resources/xyz/test.img` that means you have to `getResourcesAsStream("/xyz/test.img");`...

Comment: @howlger - I caught that too after some time. However, this does not appear to be affecting anything at this point. I went ahead and corrected it for congruency, though. Thanks!

Comment: @khmarbaise - Correct. The /com/openbravo/images/unicenta.png file is located there. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved. There were no coding issues found after many hours of troubleshooting.

Issue lays completely in the IDE.

When running from Eclipse IDE and building it is running as a 'Java Application'. Going to 'Build Executable JAR' always ended in this strange error.

After doing some research, found out about the M2E Maven Integration tools for Eclipse. Actually needed right-click my project in the Project Explorer pane then go to **Run As -> Maven build...**. From here I can setup my output file information. **NOTE:** You *must* set a Goal in the Edit Configuration window or it will not build. I used 'package' as my Goal and it built fine.

Able to now run the JAR from my Command Prompt and everything is working perfectly!